# Fourier transformation of $e^{-at}$ from $0$ to $T$

Tags: fourier-transform

I have to find the fourier transform of $g(t)$. Picture is added at the link below.

https://www.mathcha.io/editor/KkvMFWBUm3TXrhr0

I have tried this way
\begin{align}
G(f)&=\int ^{\infty }_{-\infty } g( t) \ e^{-j\omega t}\, dt\\
&=\int ^{\infty }_{-\infty } e^{-at} rect\left(\frac{t}{T} -\frac{1}{2}\right) e^{-j\omega t}\, dt\\
&=\int ^{T}_{0} e^{-at} e^{-j\omega t}\, dt\\
&=\frac{1-e^{-( a+j\omega ) T}}{a+j\omega }
\end{align}
where $$
rect(t) ~is ~unit ~rectangular ~function\\
rect(\frac{t}{T}-\frac{1}{2}) = \begin{gather*}  
\begin{cases}
  1 & \text{for }0\le t\le T\\    
  0 & \text{for }elsewhere   
\end{cases}
\end{gather*} 
$$

But i am not sure whether it's right or not.

Comment: What is "rect"?

Comment: Then I'd say that both "rect" and the second line of your calculation are unnecessary.